# How can I reuse rendered native components in react native?

Tags: react-native

In my application I have several screens and I use `ReactNative.Navigator` to navigate between them.
Following react native examples, my `renderScene` function is implemented in the following way:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    switch (routeId)
    {
        case 'Screen1': return <Screen1 navigator={navigator} />
        case 'Screen2': return <Screen2 navigator={navigator} />
        case 'Screen3': return <Screen3 navigator={navigator} />
        ... 
    }
}
```

Taking this approach, it seems that every time I navigate to a specific screen, a native element is created all over again for this screen. It means that if I navigate to this screen several times, a new native element will be created for this screen hierarchy.
For example, if my navigation flow is `Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3 -> Screen2` then the native element that was already created for `Screen2` in the first step, won't be reused for the last step.
Therefore, my question is, can I reuse the native element of a screen, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

In navigation you pushing numbers of screen class inside the navigation stack. So every-time you need to either push or pop screen from navigation stack. Now you question answer is either from it,

1) You need to create new instance of screen2.

2) you can exchange index of screens inside navigation stack (exchange top `n` index i.e. screen 3 with index `n-1` i.e. screen 2.

3) Simply pop screen 3 you will screen 2 and use it according to your functionality.